# Have the Baudhayana Grihya Sutras ever been translated into English?

Tags: vedas, rituals, translation-request, yajur-veda, grihya-sutra

There are six Vedangas or supplements to the Vedas: Siksha or prounciation, Chandas or poetic meter, Vyakarana or grammar, Nirukta or etymology, Kalpa or rituals, and Jyotisha or astrology.  My question is about Kalpa.  There are three types of Kalpa Sutras or guides to Vedic rituals: Shrauta Sutras, which tell you how to do large public Yagnas; Grihya Sutras, which tell you how to do household rituals; and Shulba Sutras, which describe the geometry of altars for Vedic rituals.

Now as you can see in my Meta answer [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/734/36), I've read many Grihya Sutra texts: the Shankhayana Grihya Sutras, the Ashvalayana Grihya Sutras, the Paraskara Grihya Sutras, the Khadira Grihya Sutras, the Gobhila Grihya Sutras, the Hiranyakeshi Grihya Sutras, the Apastamba Grihya Sutras, and the Vaikhanasa Grihya Sutras.  Almost all of these are available in English on sacred-texts.com [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/index.htm) and [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/index.htm), except for the Vaikhanasa Grihya Sutras which I've uploaded to Google Drive [here](http://gdurl.com/dQOe/download).

But there's one Grihya Sutra text I haven't read yet: the Baudhayana Grihya Sutras, which are associated with the Krishna Yajur Veda.  My question is, have the Baudhayana Grihya Sutras ever been translated into English? You can read it in Sanskrit [here](http://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/kalpa/grihya/bodhayana_grihya_sutram.pdf), but I can't seem to find an English translation.

Comment: Anga does not mean supplement. It means component/part/limb. For example our head is a part of our body and not a supplement to it.

Comment: The word Anga literally means limb, but in the context of Vedanga these texts are supplements designed to aid the study and application of the Vedas, not actual parts of the Vedas.  They're Smriti rather than Shruti.  (Although it should be noted that in the Purva Mimamsa Sutras, Jaimini does not even grant Kalpa Sutras the status of Smriti; see [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/1E9E).)

Comment: They are neither Sruti nor Smriti, They are called Vedanga. Also, what authority a Darshana has to say that? Why should everyone agree with what it says? If they were not Angas (part) why were they so called? Was there shortage of names?

Comment: @Rickross Darshana Sutras do not speak on the basis of their own authority, they make logical arguments which you can examine and judge for yourself whether they make sense or not.  In any case, Anga is used as a metaphor - just as limbs are useful for a person, Vedangas are useful for the study and application of the Vedas.  In any case, it's precisely because the Vedangas are not Shruti that they are not actual parts of the Vedas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68637/discussion-between-keshav-srinivasan-and-rickross).

Comment: @NarayanaSharma This Sutra texts, like all Sutra texts, say that only Dvijas can wear the sacred thread.

Comment: Can you quote for me?

Comment: @NarayanaSharma See the verses quoted by Adi Shankaracharya here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34107.htm

Comment: @NarayanaSharma Well I haven't found the Baudhayana Grihya Sutras in English, so I can't give you specific quotes from it as I can't read Devanagari script.  But if you can read Devanagari you can look at the Sanskrit version here: http://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/kalpa/grihya/bodhayana_grihya_sutram.pdf

Comment: Here wikipedia says according to this Sutra anyone can wear sacred thread, including Shudras. So I asked. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana#Age,_gender_and_varna_restrictions

Comment: @NarayanaSharma Wikipedia is misquoting the Baudhayana Grihya Sutras here.  The actual verse is talking about Rathakaras and not low-caste people in general.  Rathakaras are an exception to the rule of low-caste people being ineligible to do Yagnas.  This is a long-established principle discussed even in the Purga Mimamsa Sutras: http://gdurl.com/uQrG